# Print Map Rendering using QGIS

Tags: qgis, printing, rendering

When I prepare my map it looks like this in the print preview layouts:

[image: Pre Rendered Image]

However, when I print it, it looks like this (missing left and some top co-ordinates):

[image: Post rendered picture]

Why are the co-ordinates dropping off after printing?

Comment: In the printed version, there is no margin left for the coordinates on the left. Is that the print result for the 1st screenshot, without reframing the map object at all?

Comment: Thanks for answering Kasper. I'll look into the suggestion but I don't think that is the issue, as some of the co-ordinates on the top are also missing. It seems that when rendering for printing, QGIS somehow doesn't port over all the information.

Comment: I was wondering as the framing looks different between your 1st and 2nd screenshot, but maybe that's only because the screenshot is framed differently. Things you can check: 1. that your "Map item" CRS and Grid CRS (of the Map item) are the same. 2. I have noticed that sometimes the coordinates don't appear when they fall too close to the map border. Changing the zoom/framing of the map inside the map item can sort it out. One thing you can do is add a screenshot of your CRS and Grid settings in your original question